# GMOCK how to assign values to function arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, googlemock

I have a function like below:

```
FnCall(request, response);
```

where request and reply type are of a class - Message. Now I have mocked the method like below:

```
class MessageMock : public Message
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD2(FnCall, bool(const Message* request, Message*& response));
};
```

In my test case I have an expect call to FnCall

```
EXPECT_CALL(mMessageMock, FnCall(::testing::_,::testing::_));
```

My requirement is to set some dummy value in the request / response argument in function FnCall of type MessageMock - how can I set that?

=======================================================================

I tried the below code:

```
MessageMock MessageMock1, MessageMock2;

EXPECT_CALL(mMessageMock, FnCall(&mMessageMock1,
                &mMessageMock2));
```

But receive compilation error and even tried with const declaration:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'gmock_FnCall(MessageMock*, MessageMock*)'

note: candidate is:
note: testing::internal::MockSpec<bool(const Message*, Message*&)>& 

 note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'MessageMock*' to 'const testing::Matcher<Message*&>&'
```

Comment: You want to compare arguments given to the function and some expected values?

Comment: No - Message is an abstract class and I want to set dummy values for request / response - so that the flow in FnCall will behave accordingly

Comment: I think that you are using mocking in the wrong way. When you use mock, you mock some interface and expect call of mocked method on that mock.

Comment: Yes, but there are mechanism by which we can set mocked methods function arguments - the issue is that I am unable to supply of type Message cause it is an abstract class and not sure how to convert MessageMock  to Message

Comment: But that is on the function caller. Function caller will provide that argument. If the test is function caller, make so that test provide dummy object to complete interface, if not rest of the system needs to provide concrete object.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this wrong. Your expectation is just on `mMessageMock` so just that object should be mock. (You are expecting on mock instance) if the test is the caller:

```
mMessageMock.method(...)
```

you need to provide dummy objects for that call.

Lets say you have interface like this:

```
class MyInterface{
    public:
        virtual void method(MyInterface*, MyInterface*) = 0;
};
```

and you want to check is some method called on that interface. You define mock class and set expectation on that instance of that mock.

```
class MyMock : public MyInterface{
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD2(method, void(MyInterface*,MyInterface*);
};
```

For your test you need to provide Dummy object to complete interface:

```
class MyDummy : public MyInterface{
    public:
        void method(MyInterface*, MyInterface*) override{}
};
```

So, in your test add:

```
MyMock mock;
MyDummy request, response;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, method(&request, &response));
```

and if you want to test this without rest of the code. Just call that method on mock instance after you set expectation.

```
mock.method(&request,&response);
```

Here I provide dummy values.

EDIT:
Updated to improve usage of dummy objects.

Comment: Its all fine if we have to input parameter of known type like int in your example - but the issue my side is that the input parameter if of type MyInterface class - so your method would be of following signature - void method(MyInterface *, MyInterface*&) = 0. Note in actual an object of MyInterface would be created and passed.

Comment: So, just like you define your Mock object, do the same thing for the dummy object and provide that dummy objects to method call, again if you are calling from the test directly, if not someone else will provide arguments for your method.

Comment: Well I have tried that - I am in need of a mechanism where MessageMock 
 object can be converted to Message in GMOCK test cases and be passed as arguments

Comment: I have added the issue details I am facing in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160181/discussion-between-elvis-oric-and-prakash).